# Join generate Unique ID in username INSERT POST

Tags: php, mysql, oop, mysqli

I have a function to insert username in database, while the database generate unique_id column.

how do i make username get additional suffix, from unique_id column

so it will be looks like this.

username+unique_id

example:John92749

so Input Post Field will add suffix from this column.

below are my function :

```html
//Create user
function addUser($username, $reference_user_id, $user_ip_addr) {
 global $conn;

 $unique_id = mt_rand(10000,99999);

 $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT p.id FROM plans p where is_default = 1");
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 $res = $stmt->fetch();
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT into users (username, plan_id, reference_user_id, ip_addr, unique_id) 
       VALUES (:un, :pid, :ref_id, :ip_addr, :unique_id)");
 $stmt->bindParam(':un', $username);
 $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $res['id']);
 $stmt->bindParam(':ref_id', $reference_user_id);
 $stmt->bindParam(':ip_addr', $user_ip_addr);
 $stmt->bindParam(':unique_id', $unique_id);

 $stmt->execute();
 $uid = $conn->lastInsertId();
 $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT into user_plan_history (user_id, plan_id,status,created_at) VALUES (:uid, :pid,'active',:date)");
 $stmt->bindParam(':date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
 $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
 $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $res['id']);
 $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to merge two variable 
like

```
$uname = $username.''.$unique_id;
```

Then your code look like :

```
//Create user
function addUser($username, $reference_user_id, $user_ip_addr) {
    global $conn;

    $unique_id = mt_rand(10000,99999);

    $uname = $username.''.$unique_id;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT p.id FROM plans p where is_default = 1");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $res = $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT into users (username, plan_id, reference_user_id, ip_addr, unique_id) 
                            VALUES (:un, :pid, :ref_id, :ip_addr, :unique_id)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':un', $uname);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $res['id']);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ref_id', $reference_user_id);
    $stmt->bindParam(':ip_addr', $user_ip_addr);
    $stmt->bindParam(':unique_id', $unique_id);

    $stmt->execute();
    $uid = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT into user_plan_history (user_id, plan_id,status,created_at) VALUES (:uid, :pid,'active',:date)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $stmt->bindParam(':uid', $uid);
    $stmt->bindParam(':pid', $res['id']);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

this will give output : John92749

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$username = $username.$unique_id; //Append username and unique_id
```